# R lrm model with no predictors

Tags: r, logistic

I am creating multiple logistic regression models using lrm from Harrell's Design package in R.  One model I would like to make is the model with no predictors.  For example, I want to predict a constant c such that:

```
logit(Y) ~ c
```

I know I how to compute c (divide the number of "1"s by the total), what I would like is to use `lrm` so I can manipulate it as a model in a consistent way with the other models I am making.  Is this possible, and if so how?

I have tried so far:

```
library(Design)
data(mtcars)
lrm(am ~ 1, data=mtcars)
```

which gives the error:

```
Error in dimnames(stats) <- list(names(cof), c("Coef", "S.E.", "Wald Z",  :
    length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

and I have tried:

```
lrm(am ~ ., data=mtcars)
```

But this uses all the predictors, rather then none of the predictors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why this doesn't work with `lrm`.  However, R does Logistic Regression just fine with its own internal functions.  See GLM.  Here's your model, working...

```
summary(glm(am~1, data = mtcars, family=binomial(link=logit)))
```

So, unless you need something that `lrm()` from design provides, then use GLM with the binomial logit link.

Comment: This will due for now.  Is the fact that this doesn't work in the Design package a bug?

Comment: Rather a non-implemented feature, still you can send a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a dummy variable with so many ones as the number of rows in mtcars and put it formula instead of one.

Comment: It's a good idea, but

    "mtcars$dummy <- 1; lrm(am ~ dummy, data=mtcars);" 

gives back:

    singular information matrix in lrm.fit (rank= 1 ) Offending variable(s):
    dummy 
    Error in lrm(am ~ dummy, data = mtcars) : 
    Unable to fit model using “lrm.fit”